# Got error "Your clock is ahead" even the clock is correct

Tags: clock

I use Windows XP ver 2002 SP 3
Lately I got (from some we sites) the error: Your clock is ahead
I checked, the time is correct, the option to automatically set date-time is marked
How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Export the certificates from
**Trusted root CA**
and
**Third-Party Trusted root CA**
on a working machine.
THEN Import ones on the problem machine.
It helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).